# Retrive value from array id in js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am writing a php based code in which i am generating checkbox with different id and name

```
<input type="checkbox" name="settle_check[]" id="settle_check['.$res2['id'].']" value="1" onclick="calculate_discount(\''.$res2['id'].'\');"/>
```

and my function of calculate discount is as follow

```
 function calculate_discount(id){
    alert($('#settle_check['+id+']').val());
    if($('#settle_check['+id+']').is(":checked")){
        alert('Hiii');
    }
    else{
        alert('Byeee');
    }
}
```

now for every time it is not capturing the value and giving alert of undefined.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$('#settle_check\\['+id+'\\]').val()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `[]` in ID selector which are meta characters. You need to escape them.

Use

```
$('#settle_check\\['+id+'\\]').val()
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

*OR*

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('[id="settle_check[' + id +']"]').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

Instead of passing the id, pass the element itselfe like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="settle_check[]" value="1" click="calculate_discount(this);"/>
```

and update the function to:

```
function calculate_discount(element){
    alert($(element).val());
    if($(element).is(":checked")){
        alert('Hiii');
    }
    else{
        alert('Byeee');
    }
}
```

With this solution you avoid unnecessary jQuery searching.